# How can I install Windows Virtual PC on Windows 7 Home edition?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-genuine-advantage

I believe that (according to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/installing-windows-virtual-pc-on-windows-7-home-editions)) Virtual PC is supported on Windows 7 Home Premium.

However, when I go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3702 and click on Continue, I am prompted to download and run the "GenuineCheck.exe" which is supposed to generate a validation code which I can use to continue.

Except that when I run the executable, I get a message that says "This version of the Windows Genuine Advantage validation tool is no longer supported".  (Nice work, Microsoft.)

How can I get Virtual PC installed on my (valid) Windows 7 Home Premium edition?

Comment: Use Internet explorer to download the files, then you don't have to run genuinecheck.exe, it will use another method to validate.

Comment: @Moab: I tried IE, same results: I had to download & run that exe, which failed.

Comment: chris: something is wrong, you should not have to download anything to validate using IE, it may want to install an activex add-on control but that is all. All I can suggest is to download it on another PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try bypassing the stupid genuine check (before download, not during install) by getting the Windows Virtual PC and XP Mode installers directly from MS using the links [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-sp1-virtual-pc-refresh-version/) and [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/windows-7-virtual-pc-and-windows-xp-mode-official-direct-download-links/).

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Run the Diagnostic Tool.
[go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=52012](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=52012)

Option 2:
Go to [www.microsoft.com/genuine/validate](http://www.microsoft.com/genuine/validate)
Its the same thing as what you used. Just dont run it. Save it and run in compatibility mode.